# MAC Intellij 2020 installation

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2020

I have Intellij2019 installed on my MAC and recently I downloaded and installed Intellij2020 so the Applications folder contains two .app links the "Intellij Idea" and the "Intellij Idea 2020".

When I run the idea command from the command line I see it launches the 2019 version. The `/usr/local/bin/idea` I can see is pointing to 2019. Is there anyway I can install the 2020 command line version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 use `Tools` | `Create Command-line Launcher`.

If the app is installed via [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/), there is also an option to create command-line launchers automatically.